# Check if one of the 2 input fields is filled in

Tags: php, html

EDIT:

This seems to work

```
if ( empty($_POST['currentamount']) && empty($_POST['nextamount']) )
{ $error_msg ="- You didn't order any tickets.<br>"; }
```

---

EDIT:

This doesn't work :(

```
if(strlen($_POST['currentamount']) OR strlen($_POST['nextamount']) == 0)
{ $error_msg ="- You didn't order any tickets.<br>"; }
```

---

I have a contact form where people can order tickets, either for the next show or the current.
Now I want to make sure they fill in atleast one show date.

[image: Contact form]

---

- How can I send them an error if they didn't fill in atleast one of the two 'amount' fields?
- Is it possible that if they fill in one 'amount' field it NEEDS to have a selected date aswell?

---

Contact.php

```
<? 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{ 
if(strlen($_POST['name2']) == 0)
{ $error_msg ="- Please, provide us with your name.<br>"; } 

if(!empty($error_msg))
{ 
//Een van de velden werd niet goed ingevuld 
echo "<b>Your message can't be send due to the following reason:</b>    <br><br>"; 
echo $error_msg; 
echo "<br>Click on <a href='javascript:history.back(1)'>Go back</a> and provide us with your name.<br><br>"; 
}
else 
{
$recipient = "************"; //Het email adres van de persoon die vragen moet ontvangen.
$subject = "**********"; //Subject van de mail.
$header = "From: " . $_POST['uwemail'] . "\n";
$mail_body = "Contact script werd op " . date("d-m-Y") . " om " . date("H:i") . " uur uitgevoerd.\n";
*****MORE email text********
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
print "<b>IMPORTANT!</b>";
*****MORE print text********
print "<br><br>We are looking forward to meet you.";
}
{
$recip = $_SESSION['email']; //Het email adres van de persoon die vragen moet ontvangen.
$subjec = "******"; //Subject van de mail.
$head = "From: " . $_POST['uwemail'] . "\n";
$mail_body2 = "Dear". $_POST['name2'] . "\n";
mail($recip, $subjec, $mail_body2, $head);
}    
}
else
{
?>
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="contact">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                            Your personal card number
                                <input type="text" name="card2" id="card" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" placeholder="Card Number" readonly/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="text" name="name2" id="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['realName']; ?>" placeholder="Your name" readonly/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div class="row uniform 50%">
    <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
        Order tickets for our current show: Smile
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row uniform 50%">
    <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <input type="text" name="currentshow" id="currentshow" value="Current show: Smile" placeholder="" readonly/>
    </div>
    <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <select name="date1">
            <option>Select a date</option>
            <option>02 Octobre 2016 - 20h</option>
            <option>03 Octobre 2016 - 20h</option>
            <option>04 Octobre 2016 - 20h</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="2u 12u(narrower)">
            <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' name="currentamount" id="currentamount" value="" placeholder="Amount" />
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="row uniform 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                Order tickets for our next show: Sand
                    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
                    <input type="text" name="nextshow" id="nextshow" value="Next show: Sand" placeholder="" readonly/>
        </div>
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
                    <select name="date2">
                    <option>Select a date</option>
                    <option>20 Octobre 2016 - 20h</option>
                    <option>21 Octobre 2016 - 20h</option>
                    <option>23 Octobre 2016 - 20h</option>
                    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="2u 12u(narrower)">
                    <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' name="nextamount" id="nextamount" value="" placeholder="Amount" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="hidden" id="currentprice" value="10" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="hidden" id="nextprice1" value="10" placeholder="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <input name="uwemail" placeholder="Email" type="hidden"  value="noreply@mazzinitheatreproductions.com"/>
                                        </div>
                        <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                        Total price.(In EUR)
                                <input type="text" name="total2" id="total" value=""  readonly/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row uniform">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions align-center">
                                    <li><input type="submit" name="submit"value="Place Order"/></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>


<?php 
} 
?>
```

---

This code doesn't need to be there anymore, since it's auto filled in by the server.

```
if(strlen($_POST['name2']) == 0)
{ $error_msg ="- Please, provide us with your name.<br>"; }
```

Comment: Your options don't have any values. Seems like this would be causing you problems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for your required conditions at the beginning of handling your form submission. It is convenient to store any errors in an array. If there are multiple problems encountered during form validation, it may provide a better experience to your user to be presented with all of them at once, rather than fixing one thing, submitting the form again and encountering a different error.

```
if (!$_POST['date1'] && !$_POST['date2']) {
    $errors['form'] = 'You must select at least one show date.';
}
if ($_POST['currentamount'] && !$_POST['date1']) {
    $errors['current'] = 'You must select a date.';
}
if ($_POST['nextamount'] && !$_POST['date2']) {
    $errors['next'] = 'You must select a date.';
}
```

You can add more conditions to validate (proper dates, etc.) as you see fit. After checking all of your conditions, check the `$errors` variable to see if any errors were encountered. If it's empty, you can proceed with processing the submitted data, and if not, you can use the values in the error array to prompt the user in the specific place on your form where the error occurred.

Comment: One problem I seem to encounter... Cause I use a value for my date field it sees this field as filled in immediately. A way around this problem? It needs to be dropdown for the users to choose a date.

Comment: You can include a default option with an empty value.

Comment: Is there a way to add a placeholder to an option field?

Comment: You should be able to modify your current one with an empty value: `<option value="">Select a date</option>`

Comment: This worked: <option disabled selected> ^^
Thanks for the help mate!

Answer (score 1):

First you'd want to check the date fields are not empty, then you need to make sure the date is in the right format (xx/xx/xxxx) then you need to validate the date to ensure it's a correct date.

Like so:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    if ($_POST['date'] == '') {
        $error_msg = 'Field is empty';
    } else {    
        list($dd, $mm, $yy) = explode('/', $_POST['date']);
        $start = $yy . '-' . $mm . '-' . $dd . ' 00:00:00';
        if ($mm == '' || $dd == '' || $yy == '') {
            $error_msg = 'Date is not in a valid format';
        } else {
            if (!checkdate($mm, $dd, $yy)) {
                $error_msg = 'Date is not a valid date';
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($error_msg)) {
        // Continue
    }
}
```

Comment: But the date only needs to be checked if the 'amount' value is filled in. I have 2 'date' fields and 2 'amount' fields. The user needs to fill in atleast 1 'amount' field and when they choose to enter for the current project, it needs to check the date of the current.

Comment: Then you add an `IF` statement to only validate the date if the amount field is not empty

Comment: And do you have any idea how I can check if they filled in 1 of the 2 'amount' fields? The user has to fill in atleast one 'amount' field (either the current or next)